# How to compare a word to any elements in an array

Tags: jquery, xcode, html

I am trying to find a word (that a player will make out of random letters) from a text file(dictionary)

```
var words = [];

$(document).ready(function()
              {
              $.get("dictionary.txt", function(txt)
                    {                           
                        words = txt.split("\n"); //get array of all words                      
                    });
              });


$(function()
{
$("#playButton").on("click",function()
                  {
                     for(var k = 0; k < words.length; k++)
                     {
                       if(completedWord == words[k])
                       {
                          alert("hi");
                       }

                     }

                     if($.inArray(completedWord,words) > -1)
                     {
                        alert(completedWord + " is in array");
                     }

                  });

});
```

The part where I am having trouble is that the alerts are only displayed when I enter in the last word in the array/text file.

The text file contains "one", "two" and "three" (for example purposes), when I enter "three" the alerts are displayed but not for "one" and "two".

Is there any way that I can enter any one of the options and display the alerts.

Thank you.

//////////////////////////////

This is my code for one of the buttons for choosing a letter

```
var chosenWord = new Array();
var orderLetterChosen = 0;

var enterLetter7 = function()
{
    if(enterLetterOnce7 == false)
    {
        chosenWord[orderLetterChosen] = dice7[randomNumber7] ;//enter letter from dice into empty array
        orderLetterChosen++; //chosenWord moves to next element
        enterLetterOnce7 = true; //only click it once
    }
};
```

I have seven others like this.

```
completedWord = "";
for(var i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++)
{
    completedWord = completedWord + chosenWord[i];
}
```

The above is in my main function.

Comment: Place your code for reading the variable `completedWord` here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working. Probably the problem is where/how/when you get the value for `completedWord` variable.

Look this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JMuSB/

I'm reading the value for `completedWord` inside the click event:

```
$("#playButton").on("click", function() {
     var completedWord = $("#completed").val();
     ...
});
```

And it works fine.

Comment: I have a button which represents a letter, i have 8 different buttons for 8 random letters to make a word from.  I have an array which holds the letters i choose and i put the letters from the array and make it into a string which is the completedWord variable

Comment: The problem probably is on logic for the buttons. Make a fiddle on jsFiddle or include this code in your question body.

Comment: I think the logic that build the words is not correct. If you the `completedWord = 'two'` for example, then everything works fine. Maybe the logic that build the word is not working properly and buiding `tow` instead of `two` for example.

Comment: Its not the completedWord variable thats the problem. I created a new array which holds 3 strings and added it to my $.inArray method and it works but not for my text file made variable which holds the same strings. Thanks for your help

Comment: Got it. Check for white spaces in your file. What exactly is the content for `words` after you fill it with contents of the file? Take a look on your browser console to see the contents of that array and compare with a "manual filled" array.

Comment: There are no whitespaces, I put in an alert for my new array which gives me one,two,three but my alert for my text file array gives me back the same but on top of each other instead of beside each other. Both are an object when i do a typeof alert.